# Is there a reducing option for vertical indent lines on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter

I am using Visual Studio Code for Flutter development but those indent lines are a little bit annoying for me. Are there any option to reduce the thickness? 
[Here is the screenshot on VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI5QB.png)